# startActivityForResult not working TabGroupActivity in android

Tags: android, tabs, paypal, activitygroup

I have used [Experience - Multiple Android Activities in a TabActivity](http://ericharlow.blogspot.com/2010/09/experience-multiple-android-activities.html) to implement tab.
I have the following condition.
**MainActivity extends TabActivity** (Tab1,Tab2,Tab3)
**TabGroup1Activity extends TabGroupActivity** (class from above url)

In **TabGroup1Activity**:

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    startChildActivity("MyActivity", new Intent(this,MyActivity.class));


}
```

And in **MyActivity.java** class i used

```
        PayPalPayment payment = SimplePayment();
        Intent checkoutIntent = PayPal.getInstance().checkout(payment,
                MyActivity.this,new ResultDelegate());
        startActivityForResult(checkoutIntent, request);
```

But it doesnot execute **onActivityResult** method.
When i run this code in another project without tabs and activity group, it goes to **onActivityResult**, works fine.
what should i do to make it work here ?
Help Please !!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510280/android-onactivityresult-is-always-0/4510394#4510394

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `onActivityResult` is called on the `ActivityGroup` and not on the `subActivity` of your `tabgroupActivity`.

So override the method `onActivityResult` , and then create an `abstract method` on the mother class of your `SubActivities` ( on the `TabActivityGroup` i think ), and override it on each subActivity .

Comment: Is there anything i should write inside onActivityResult method in TabActivityGroup ??

Comment: you will just call your abstract method  ,and this abstract method , will be overrided on your subactivities , and then put in it your code :)? sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 1):

```
       Intent intent = new        Intent(v.getContext(),PlayStation.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

      AppplicationData app1 = UrlSet.get(i);            
     intent.putExtra("Url", "" + app1.getUrlLink());
                        intent.putExtra("URLName", app1.getUrlName());
                        intent.putExtra("PrevActivity", "UserUrl");
                        View view = getLocalActivityManager()
                                .startActivity("PlayStaion", intent)
                                .getDecorView();
                        setContentView(view);
```