# startActivityForResult resultcode always 0

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm trying to get edited list back from activity 2 to activity 1.
Here is my code:

```
public void listDataSms(ArrayList<MySmsLog> stringList) {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelableArrayList(NUMBER_LIST, stringList);
    Intent i = new Intent(this, MyCommonListActivity.class);
    i.putExtra(WHO_INT, SMS_LOG);
    i.putExtras(bundle);
    startActivityForResult(i, SMS_LOG);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == SMS_LOG) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            ArrayList<MySmsLog> mySmsLogs = (data.getParcelableArrayListExtra(PICK_SMS_LOG));
            mainLog.setSmsLog(mySmsLogs);
        } 

        if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // do something if there is no result
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    Bundle result = new Bundle();
    switch (who) {
        case SMS_LOG:
            result.putParcelableArrayList(MainActivity.PICK_SMS_LOG, mySmsLogList);
            break;
    }

    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    intent.putExtras(result);
}
```

But I never get `setSmsLog` because `resultCode` is always `0`.
I tried [Android onActivityResult is always 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510280/android-onactivityresult-is-always-0) this but with no result. 
Even if I change my condition to  `if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {do smth}` program ends with `NullPointerException`.

Comment: @bwegs it's the request code. @previ how does your `MyCommonListActivity` activity terminate?

Answer (score 7):

Assuming that `onBackPressed()` from your code shown above is from `MyCommonListActivity`, that is too late to call `setResult()`. At best, your code might work if you call `super.onBackPressed()` as the last thing, not the first. The typical solution is to call `setResult()` and `finish()` as soon as the user taps on something in a `ListView` or otherwise chooses the particular item to work with, rather than wait until the user presses BACK.

Comment: I moved with that super.onBackPressed() and it´s working now! I know that using BACK is not so good solution, but unfortunately i need it in this example. Thank you!
Just one more question, why should be super.onBackPressed() last thing in my method?

Comment: @previ: You need to call `setResult()` before `finish()`. The default behavior of `onBackPressed()` calls `finish()`. Hence, your call to `super.onBackPressed()` calls `finish()`, and you need to do `setResult()` before that.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put super.onBackPressed(); after intent.putExtras(result);